# Allowing multiple users to create directories over SFTP so the new directories keep the same permissions

Tags: linux, sftp, chmod

I want to make a webserver with multiple users allowed to login through SFTP to a specific folder, `www`.

Multiple users are added, lets say `user1` and `user2`, and all of them belonging to the `www-data` group. The `www` directory has an owner `www-data` and a group `www-data`.

I have used `chmod -R 775` on the `www` folder, but after I try to create a folder `test` through my SFTP server (using Filezilla) the group of the directory created has only `r` and `x` permissions, and I am not able to log in with the second user `user2` and create a directory within `www/test` due to a lack of `w` permission to the group.

I also tried using `chmod 2775` on `www` directory, but without luck.

Can somebody explain to me, how can I make it so that a newly created directory inherits the root directory group permissions?

Comment: puts a sticky on the group permission g+s

Comment: Whats does "puts a sticky on the group permission g+s" mean? (I imagine it is the sticky bit).  Also, if this is an answer, you should submit it as one.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can specify different default  umask for your SSH server. By default it is 022. You should set it to 002

[Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/228396/how-to-setup-sshs-umask-for-all-type-of-connections) is good explanation how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem.
I had a ftp server and created a directory-structure. Loggin in via ftp worked for my desired users.
But I created that directory-structure with root and so the child-folders belonged to root. That's why users didn't get permissions in that folders (only read).

Check that your folders belong to the right group/user.